I'm experiencing an issue with the autocomplete function in Google Colab
The autocompletion feature in Google Colab is not working as expected, particularly on my tablet(Samsung Tab S9 Ultra). It functions normally on my laptop.
When I type the following code:
1)"from sklearn.datasets" and then press space,
2)It autocompletes to "from sklearn.sklearn.datasets", which is causing issues.
I've tried restarting Colab, logging in with a different account, and turning off autocompletion in the settings, but the problem persists.
This issue is happening with all my code, for example:
1)When I type "df.info" and then press '(',
2)It autocompletes to "df.df.info()".
I'm using both Chrome and Edge, and the issue occurs in both browsers.
Could you please help me resolve this issue?"
I'm expecting Google Colab's autocomplete to suggest "df.info()" when I input "df.info(" and then press the opening parenthesis.
